# What is the difference between Expressions and Statements in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm new in Scala world and want to know what is the difference between Expressions and Statements and Why if-else is used for expression, not statements. And if there is a way to use statement in if-else?

Comment: "_And if there is a way to use statement in if-else_". Why?

Comment: @BoristheSpider just curious. If it's impossible than ok

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**EDIT**: As pointed out by @Jörg W Mittag in the comments, this answer is in fact wrong: [statements do exist in the Scala spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#statements):

> Statements occur as parts of blocks and templates. A statement can be an import, a definition or an expression, or it can be empty.

I leave the original answer, as I think it is still valuable as a practical answer to the OP's question.

---

**Orignal answer**

Pedantically speaking, there is no such thing as a statement in Scala. There are definitions (such as `def` and `class`) and expressions. Everything that would be called a statement in other languages is just an expression.

For example, many people would call the following "line", which prints to the console, a statement:

```
println("hello")
```

In Scala, this is an expression. For example, it can be assigned to a value:

```
val x = println("hello")
```

In this case, `x` is assigned the value `()` (pronounced `unit`) of type `Unit`.

"Theory" aside, it is common practice to call an expression that always returns `()` a statement. Which means that the above `println("hello")` can also be considered as a statement.

Let us now come back to `if/else`. Since everything is an expression, this `if/else` is an expression:

```
if (cond) 3 else 5
```

but so is

```
if (cond)
  println("hello")
else
  println("bye")
```

In the latter example, though, the `if/else` always returns `()` (because both `println`s return `()`), and you can therefore call this `if/else` a statement.

Comment: I wrote a an answer along the same lines two hours ago, then opened up the SLS to amend it with links, and much to my surprise found the definitions of statements and statement sequences in the spec :-/

Comment: Care to provide a link or a section number?

Comment: nvm, I found 'em: http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#statements That is ... surprising ^^

Answer (score 7):

An *expression* is anything that can be evaluated to produce a *value*.  When a *statement* is evaluated, it causes side-effects to occur but does not reduce to a value.

A useful rule of thumb is that if you can put it on the right-hand side of an assignment, it's an expression.

```
val x = (anything legal here must be an expression)
```

If you *can't* put it on the right-hand side of an assignment, it's probably a statement.  For example, none of these are legal because the bits on the right-hand sides are statements:

```
val x = import scala.collection.mutable  // import is a statement
val x = def someFunction() = { ... }  // Function definition is a statement
val x = val y = 42  // Variable assignment is a statement
```

Scala, like many of the functional-first languages, has very few "pure" statements.  Instead, many constructs that people think of (and refer to as) statements are expressions that evaluate to `Unit`:

```
scala> val x = print("hello world")  // a "print statement" is actually an expression
x: Unit = ()
scala> val x = for (i in Array(1, 2, 3)) println("Hello " + i) // for loops are expressions too!
x: Unit = ()
```

Treating "if statements" as expressions is actually quite handy:

```
val meal = if (hungry) Some(food) else None
```

tl;dr: The technical difference between a statement and an expression is that an expression evaluates to a value while a statement does not.  Informally, many people use the term "statement" to refer to anything that is evaluated only for side effects, but many of those "statements" are actually expressions that evaluate to `Unit`.

Answer (score 1):

Statements are more imperative and expressions are more functional. If that is what you are looking for. Statements are like assignments and therefore, equated to "var" rather than "val" and they don't print out the values,you'll need a println(s"...") to get the value out of them. Whereas, expressions produce the value right away and have a type.

Answer (score 1):

> Everything in Scala is an Expression!

### Theory:

- Instructions/Statements are ***executed*** in imperative languages like Java but Expressions are ***evaluated*** in Functional languages(Declarative programming) like Scala.
- Instruction means ***Do something*** for me but Expression means give me the ***Value*** of something.

### Practical:

#### If else expression:

```
val aCondition = true
val aConditionValue = if(aCondition) 4 else 2
println(aConditionValue)
```

To prove this we can just use this Expression in println directly

```
println(if(aCondition) 4 else 2)
```

**Note:** Here If else expression is giving the value instead of setting/doing something based on condition.