# Creating a list of StructFields from data frame

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I need to ultimately build a schema from a CSV.  I can read the CSV into data frame, and I've got a case class defined.

```
case class metadata_class (colname:String,datatype:String,length:Option[Int],precision:Option[int])
val foo = spark.read.format("csv").option("delimiter",",").option("header","true").schema(Encoders.product[metadata_class.schema).load("/path/to/file").as[metadata_file].toDF()
```

Now I'm trying to iterate through that data frame and build a list of StructFields. My current effort:

```
val sList: List[StructField] = List(
  for (m <- foo.as[metadata_class].collect) {
    StructField[m.colname,getType(m.datatype))
})
```

That gives me a type mismatch:

```
found  : Unit
required: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField
      for (m <- foo.as[metadata_class].collect) {
             ^
```

What am I doing wrong here?  Or am I not even close?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not usual to use `for-loop` in scala. `For loop` has `Unit` return type, and in your code, result value of `sList` will be `List[Unit]`:

```
val sList: List[Unit] = List(
  for (m <- foo.as[metadata_class].collect) {
    StructField(m.colname, getType(m.datatype))
  }
)
```

but you declared `sList` as `List[StructField]` this is the cause of compile error.

I suppose you should use `map` function instead of `for loop` for iterate on `metadata_class` objects and create `StructFields` from them:

```
val structFields: List[StructField] = foo.as[metadata_class]
  .collect
  .map(m => StructField(m.colname, getType(m.datatype)))
  .toList
```

you will earn `List[StructField]` such way.

In scala language every statement is expression with return type, `for-loop` also and it return type is `Unit`.

read more about statements/expressions:

- [statement vs expression in scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34962889/what-is-the-difference-between-expressions-and-statements-in-scala)
- [statements and expressions in scala](https://www.learningjournal.guru/article/scala/functional-programming/statements-and-expressions-in-scala/)