# Scala method does not exit after if statement

Tags: scala

I have following piece of code in Scala

```
def countChange(money: Int, coins: List[Int]): Int = {
    println(s"countChange(${money}, ${coins}) - ${coins.isEmpty}")
    if money < 0 || coins.isEmpty then 0
    if money == 0 then 1
    else
      println(s"${coins.head}")
      -1

  }
```

I am invoking the function with following arguments.

```
assertEquals(countChange(1, List()), 0)
```

The output is

```
countChange(1, List()) - true

java.util.NoSuchElementException: head of empty list
 
    at scala.collection.immutable.Nil$.head(List.scala:662)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Nil$.head(List.scala:661)
    at recfun.RecFun$.countChange(RecFun.scala:45)
    at recfun.RecFunSuite.$init$$$anonfun$5(RecFunSuite.scala:27)
```

Question: Why the code execution should go to println statement? It should  return when the as the `coins.isEmpty` function should be **true**.
I am using scala version - 3.3.0

Comment: Your second `if` should be a `else if`. I recommend you learn to use a debugger to debug such cases ;)

Comment: Exactly, I already got it working. i.e. Code works fine with if-elseif-else. But what I could not understand(even with debugger) is that why the first 'if' condition is not terminated/returning the function when its true.

Comment: Why would it return from the method?

Comment: The return value of a function is its last expression. There's no explicit `return` in Scala to return something in the middle of a function. Well.. actually _there is_ but you should not use it because it doesn't work in the way you'd expect. Nobody use it in Scala.

Comment: This now makes sense. It worked with I use explicit 'return'. Thanks !

Comment: @ChotaBheem don't use `return` in Scala! [Here's why](https://tpolecat.github.io/2014/05/09/return.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code

```scala
def countChange(money: Int, coins: List[Int]): Int = {
    println(s"countChange(${money}, ${coins}) - ${coins.isEmpty}")
    if money < 0 || coins.isEmpty then 0
    if money == 0 then 1
    else
      println(s"${coins.head}")
      -1

  }
```

is equivalent to

```scala
def countChange(money: Int, coins: List[Int]): Int = {
    println(s"countChange(${money}, ${coins}) - ${coins.isEmpty}")
    val foo = if money < 0 || coins.isEmpty then 0
    val bar = if money == 0 then 1
      else
        println(s"${coins.head}")
        -1
    
    bar
  }
```

`foo` is unused (so the result of the first `if` is discarded), then execution proceeds to `bar` (the second `if` will be returned by the function because it is the last expression).

Comment: Okay. Is this how scala works? Could you help me where I can understand more on this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57733366/6247489